# "import cv2" UnicodeDecodeError on Windows

Tags: python, opencv, encoding, ipython

I am trying to "import cv2" in my IPython console but get a systematic: `UnicodeDecodeError` error.

I am currently with a "ascii" default encoding but switching to "utf-8" does not do the trick. The other posts I found on the subject referred to parsing the culprit input string but, in my case, it is during the import of the OpenCV package, so I have no control over it.

Any idea of what is happening? (it used to work but for some reason stopped all of a sudden).

Note:  on a Ubuntu console, the encoding is "utf-8" and it works; below the full traceback:

```
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3049, in run_code
    self.showtraceback()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1848, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1240, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1157, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, elist, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 511, in structured_traceback
    lines = ''.join(self._format_exception_only(etype, value))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 623, in _format_exception_only
    Colors.Normal, s))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Please show us the **full traceback** of the exception.

Comment: Traceback added; thanks

Comment: Hrm, that traceback is next to useless, as the error is in the *IPython traceback handling*.

Comment: Is there an exception when you don't use IPython but use Python directly to run the import?

Comment: Probably related: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/198, I strongly suspect you have a non-ASCII character in your path somewhere.

Comment: But to be explicit: you have 2 problems: You have an exception when importing `cv2`, *and* you have a new exception when IPython tries to display the traceback for that error.

Comment: OK, I think I figure it out; it was a matter of 32 versus 64 installation; I reinstalled my python using a 32 bits and cv2 imports correctly....

Thanks

Comment: You may still have this problem from time to time; if something else breaks the traceback issue could re-surface.

Comment: OK, thanks; great help!!!